# Doing a scipy.optimize.root runs out of memory, what are good alternatives?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

So I'm trying to use `scipy.optimize.root` but I'm running out of memory, the reason being there isn't enough memory to calculate the jacobian.

I was wondering what alternative I might be able to use given my memory constraint?, or is there a way to circumvent it somehow?

My input size is ~400,000 and the output is similar, meaning the jacobian is 400,000^2 which is a killer...

Please let me know if you have any suggestions to make the question clearer.

**UPDATE**

I think I've figured out a way to calculate the jacobian at any given point efficiently. The documentation of `scipy.optimize.root` states the following:

> If jac is a Boolean and **is True, fun is assumed to return the value of Jacobian along with the objective function**. If False, the Jacobian will be estimated numerically. jac can also be a callable returning the Jacobian of fun. In this case, it must accept the same arguments as fun.

I'm guessing from the highlighted point what it means is if `fun(x)` is my funcion it gives something like:

```
f, jac = fun(x)
```

where f = f(x) and jac = jacobian(x).

right?

Comment: Which _method_ are you using and what is your _jac_ argument set to?

Comment: Using default for both, ie not passing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `method='krylov'`.

See also http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#root-finding-for-large-problems

If you know the jacobian, you can write your function so that `f, jac = fun(x)` and give the `jac=True` option to `root`. However, given that several of the methods do not support sparse jacobians, this may not help you.

The next best thing is then to use use the sparse jacobian as a preconditioner for the Krylov method.